# Sharepoint API how to read file havin only sharing link to it

Tags: python, api, sharepoint

I'm using python office365 library to access sharepoint documents. I don't know how to access file via API that have been shared with me by sharing link. I need to get this file content and if possible metadata (last modify date). Could anyone help?
The user that I'm using have no access to this sharepoint folder other than a sharing link to a single file.

I tried many variations of normal file access API, bot by hand and by office365 library. I couldnt find a way to access a file when I have only sharing link to it.

My sharing link looks like that:

`https://[redacted].sharepoint.com/:x:/s/[redacted]/dir1/dir2/ESd0HkNNSbJMhQFavQsr9-4BNHC2rHSWsnbs3zRdjtZsC3g` so there is not really a filename here and I cannot read via API content of any folder per se because I have an error `Attempted to perform an unathorized operation.`. Authentication goes fine (when i mistake password I get different error).

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, you can use the following Rest API to read file (get file content):

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/xxx/Library_Name/Folder Name')/Files('Document.docx')/$value
```

If you want to get last modify date, you can use the following Rest API to get the **`Modified`** field：

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test_library')/Items?$select=Modified
```

Comment: I've tired this approach, but it looks like I have no permisions to go through folder or access files by its relative path. I have only my sharing link that is working (I've updated my question with example of sharing link).